# JWT refresh Token Implementation

Tags: javascript, express, jwt, refresh-token

Instead of returning two tokens after login, can I put the refresh token inside the access token?

When the access token becomes expired, user needs to pass the expired token to get a new access token. When the expired token reached to server I will extract the refresh token from it and will check the expiry time of the refresh token if it's ok then I will return a new token with the same refresh token within it. If it's not ok then the user will be logged out and need to be login.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to save a refresh token inside of an access token, and then access it on refresh but I don't see why you would want to do that? I never seen anyone do that so I would say it maybe isnt good practice. I would just stick to keeping them separate in the header.

Comment: I am developing oauth and I don't wanna to increase android/web developer task by returning two token. I want to use one token everywhere. If you never seen anyone doing like that, means may be I m the first who is thinking like that.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I think you're overestimating how much more work it is to store them separately.

Comment: You could also try btoa(JSON Object), which produces a string representation of your Object, and then send a single "Token" to the API. This way, your string can be decoded into the JSON representation again, and still contain all information (Auth token, refresh token, Token age...) 

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the refresh token with the access token. But keep in mind, that if you don't follow the JWT way, your code will not be compatible with other programs and API.
Also, it might be a good practice to refresh your token on every request to your API, not only if it is nearly close to expiration.

Not sure if that is best-practice, but I do so in one of my Node Services:
https://github.com/kihyoun/system-wizard/blob/master/src/api/SyncServer.tsx#L74 (client)
https://github.com/kihyoun/system/blob/master/sync/src/index.ts (server)

Edit:

If you want to combine both tokens into one single "token", you could probably do something like this:

`client`

```js
const authentication = {
  accessToken: "your accesstoken...",
  refreshToken: "your refreshToken...",
  action: "getBlogPosts"
};

const data = btoa(authentication) // this creates a single ASCII String
api.post('/auth', data).then(result => {
  if (result.status === 200) {
    console.log('auth successful')   
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid credentials')
  }
})
```

`server`

```js
api.post('/auth', (request, response) => {
    const data = atob(request.data);
    if (jwt.verify(data.accessToken) {
      this.action = data.action;
      switch (data.action) {
        case "getBlogPosts": //...do some stuff
...
...
```